# How to load one div after another upon form submit using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Basically I have three questions that I need to ask from the user about a website that is being shown inside an iframe.

I have a simple html form above the iframe that will submit the users answer for the processor.php to be processed.

After the first question I need to load two more, one after the other, but in a way that the iframe stays intact so the entire page must not be refreshed.

Here is what I have so far:

The form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <span id="surveyQuestion">Question 1</span><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="firstQuestion" value="Question 1">
    <span class="info">0</span>
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="0">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="1">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="2">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="3">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="4">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="5">
    <span class="info">5</span>
</form>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("input.radioButton").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'processor.php',
            data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $("#surveyBox").load("question2.php #secondQuestion > *");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am using `$("#surveyBox").load("question2.php #secondQuestion > *");` to load question2.php where there is a div with id secondQuestion that looks like this:

```
<div id="secondQuestion">
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    $("input.radioButton").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'processor.php',
            data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
            success: function () {
            alert('Done');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <span id="surveyQuestion">Question 2</span><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="secondQuestion" value="Question 2">
    <span class="info">0</span>
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="0">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="1">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="2">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="3">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="4">
    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="response" value="5">
    <span class="info">5</span>
</form>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I do this the `submit` feature inside the newly loaded div doesn't work any more. I don't get the confirmation in the form of "done" alert box.

I read about the `.on()` function, but I think it's a bit over my head right now???

I also must ask: is this even a sensible idea or can I hold the questions in another place altogether and call them one after the other in some other way? Because right now I would need to load a question3.php after the second etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option would be to load all of the elements on the page to begin with. Disable all of the form elements after the first one and hide their wrapping divs. On success unhide and enable each subsequent question.

Something like this...

```
<div id="question1">
    <form id="myForm1" action="" method="post">
        <span id="surveyQuestion">Question 1 ...
    </form>
</div>
<div id="question2" style="display: none">
    <form id="myForm2" action="" method="post">
        <span id="surveyQuestion">Question 2....
    </form>
</div>
<div id="question3" style="display: none">
    <form id="myForm3" action="" method="post">
        <span id="surveyQuestion">Question 3....
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $("#myForm1 input.radioButton").change(function(){
        submitForm(1, 2);
    });
    $("#myForm2 input.radioButton").change(function(){
        submitForm(2, 3);
    });
    $("#myForm3 input.radioButton").change(function(){
        submitForm(3, null);
    });

    submitForm = function(thisQuestionNumber, nextQuestionNumber){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'processor.php',
            data: $('#myForm'+thisQuestionNumber).serialize(),
            success: function () {
                if(nextQuestionNumber != null){
                    $("question"+nextQuestionNumber).show();
                    $("#myForm"+nextQuestionNumber).enable();
                } else {
                    // any code to tie things up
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Although if you don't absolutely need to submit them one at a time you could refactor this code so that the form wraps everything and hide and show each question as needed. Then submit only after the last question is answered. Like this...

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <div id="question1">
        <span id="surveyQuestion">Question 1</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" class="radioButtonGroup1" name="response1" value="0">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="question2" style="display: none">
        <span id="surveyQuestion">Question 2</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" class="radioButtonGroup2" name="response2" value="0">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="question3" style="display: none">
        <span id="surveyQuestion">Question 3</span><br/>
        <input type="radio" class="radioButtonGroup3" name="response3" value="0">
        ...
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $("input.radioButtonGroup1").change(function(){
        $("question2").show();
    });
    $("input.radioButtonGroup2").change(function(){
        $("question3").show();
    });
    $("input.radioButtonGroup3").change(function(){
        submitForm();
    });

    submitForm = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'processor.php',
            data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                // any code to tie things up
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I like the second one better where form gets submitted after all the questions have been answered, but I am confused about your code- there is only one form, but you are referring to 3 different forms in your function?

Comment: Sorry, got ahead of myself on that one, I have changed it to reflect the new full wrap form.

Comment: Thanks. I added # in front of the question1,2 and 3 to indicate the ID and now it works great.

Comment: One more quick question. How do I add a variable into my ajax data? I need to add var src = $('#sitesFrame').attr('src'); to be passed along with the form in data: $('#myForm').serialize(), because I need the url from the iframe as well...

Comment: You are doing a post so you can add an input type=hidden to the form with that value and it will be automatically picked up by the serialize function and added to the post.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options - using ".on" as you mentioned or hiding as mentioned in the other answer.

**Using .on()**

```
$("#surveyBox").on("submit", "#firstQuestion form", function(){
    //form1 ajax
});
$("#surveyBox").on("submit", "#secondQuestion", function(){
    //form2 ajax
});
$("#surveyBox").on("submit", "#thirdQuestion", function(){
    //form3 ajax
});
```

**Hiding Forms**

With the html -

```
<div id="firstQuestion">
    //first form
</div>
<div id="secondForm">
    //second form
</div>
<div id="thirdForm">
    //third form
</div>
```

Add the following to the top of your jQuery functiion -

```
$("#secondForm").hide();
$("#thirdForm").hide();
```

Then in the success functions each of your ajax calls you can hide the submitted form and show the next form.  ie

```
$("#firstForm").hide();
$("#secondForm").show();
```

Comment: You have an error in your on() calls. First parameter should be event, like that: $("#surveyBox").on("submit", "#firstQuestion form", function(){
    //form1 ajax
});

Comment: I haven't yet tried using .on() but by simply hiding the divs all sorts of strange things happen. Sometimes the question2 goes past so quickly you don't really notice and question3 gets displayed. Sometimes the question2 gets stuck, but when clicked twice question3 goes past really quickly etc. Sometimes the same question gets shown twice and sometimes after one submit nothing happens...

Comment: It sounds to me like all your ajax calls are getting called when you are choosing a radio option.  This could be because you are still wrapping your ajax calls in `$("input.radioButton").change(function()` (which is called when any "input" with the class "radiobutton" is changed) rather than something like `$("#firstQuestion input.radioButton").change(function()` (which will only be called when an "input" with the class "radiobutton" that is within a container called "firstQuestion" is changed).